# Copying a table using psycopg2 copy_from and copy_expert?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to copy table rows from an old database into a new one using the [copy](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#copy) commands available in psycopg2.  I thought I could redirect through [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) like the following

```
io = StringIO.StringIO('')
whereClause = " SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE home_city='%s' "%(
                 ','.join(columns), tablename, city,
                     )
old_db_cursor.execute(whereClause)
rows = old_db_cursor.fetchall()
logger.info('Should get %d rows',len([r for r in rows]))
sql = 'COPY (%s) to STDOUT'%(whereClause,)
old_db_cursor.copy_expert( sql, io,  )
new_db_cursor.copy_from( io, tablename, columns=columns)
new_db_connection.commit()
```

where the logging shows I should get 30,000 rows.  But I get no new rows despite the lack of error messages.   For what it's worth, checking the length of `io.read()` shows it is zero.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question, it is necessary to rewind the StringIO object, using

```
io.seek(0)
```

Comment: I just spent over an hour trying to figure out why `copy_from` isn't working for it to just be this.  They really need to put a warning in the docs to do this.